# How to use CMultiFileUpload in Form builder?

Tags: yii

Is it possible to use [CMultiFileUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMultiFileUpload) in [Form builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder, the form builder uses `CFormInputElement` to define the elements of the form.

Look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormInputElement

It tells you that type can be a class name of a widget that has a `model` attribute and an `attributes` attribute. Happily CMultiFileUpload meets this criteria. So I suspect `'type'=>'CMultiFileUpload'` should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use „live“ `CMultiFileUpload` class – without quotes.